# Booting ubuntu via VirtualBox on Win7 goes to black screen after this prompt

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, vagrant

![GNU GRUB Screen]https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S24N.jpg

99% of the time The first option is selected by VirtualBox in under 3 seconds, the other 1% it pauses for me to actually choose. No matter the option I choose, the next screen will be a black screen with an unblinking prompt and that's it.

Additionally, VirtualBox is being initiated via a vagrant up on Windows 7 via a cygwin commandline.

I'd appreciate as many ideas as possible, random spitballs are also welcome!

Comment: Is the guest 64-bit? Is VT-x enabled in BIOS?

Comment: And where is the box from? Did you download it or build it yourself?

Comment: Guest is 64 bit. Did not build it. It's a generic build for the firm I work for. I must add that it was built on a Mac OS

Comment: OK, boot your Windows machine into BIOS and check if the VT-x (or some "virtualization" setting) is enabled. Although normally VirtualBox should detect that and complain in the GUI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. As embarrassing as it may sound, simply enabling Hardware Virtualization from the BIOS solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The blinking cursor can be a number of things.  Are you able to CTRL + F2 to get to a terminal, or is it completely dead?

If you boot to a live cd and [mount the hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password), is your stuff on the file system?

Lastly, have you tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWRCv.jpg)? :)

Comment: After a few tries I got the screen back up and tried CTRL+F2 on the black screen. Nothing, no response, no change. I removed all files, did a cold reboot of the host and when I got back to the screen I chose the recovery mode option given the instructions in [mount the hard drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) . I got this [screen](http://imgur.com/jbIpZEn) and then it hung again. I'm hunting down straws as we speak